# How can I remove an unknown device from my wifi network?

Tags: wifi, ddos, countermeasure

I have an OnHub (from Google), and there is a device I don't know on my wifi network. Is there some way for me to kick it, or DDoS it, whether through some command line command on windows or ubuntu, or through the OnHub app?

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, you want to DDoS yourself, right? The self-flagellation is strong with this one. You'd do well with the rest of us in the DMZ.

Comment: I want to DDoS a specific device on my wifi, @MarkBuffalo

Comment: That will probably DDoS *you*. :p

Comment: As an aside, are you sure it's not just one of your devices that you've failed to give a meaningful name to?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If it can get on now, and you kick it off (rebooting your router would definitely kick it off, for example), it's just going to get on again.

To kick it permanently, do the following, in this order:

- Change your router's admin password
- Download updates for your router
- Disable WPS if it's enabled

  - ESPECIALLY WPS-PIN (the "enter the digits") because it's ridiculously vulnerable; see [Reaver](http://www.kalitutorials.net/2014/04/hack-wpawpa2-wps-reaver-kali-linux.html)
- Change your Wifi to use WPA2-AES
- Change the PW to use a long (20 character plus), strong (cryptographically random, like [KeePass](http://keepass.info/) generates) password.
- You will need to change the Wifi password on all your devices, of course, but this should last you for awhile.
- Don't give out the new password to anyone.
- Don't let them put it in their device; they can pull the password out of their device at their leisure.

Comment: Reaver is broken, the WPS bugs are fixed long ago. Even the reaver-like program which uses random lladdr every time it is locked out cannot rapidly crack WPS due to throttling.

Answer (score 4):

You are asking the wrong questions.

- How did they connect to your wifi? If you don't have a password, password-protect your wifi.
- If you do have a password, change it
- If a device is connected, most wifi routers have a block feature. Use it.
- Use the wifi router to figure out what the device is. Most routers will tell you the name and some will tell you if it is an iPhone, printer, or something else. While this cannot be 100% accurate, it will give you an idea of what is connected to your network.

Comment: The block feature is worthless against any semi-competent attacker; they just change their MAC address with macchanger or similar.

Comment: @Anti-weakpasswords Sure. But that should include changing your wifi password. I'll edit my post to make that more clear. What bothers me is that the OP immediately jumps to DDoSing the device rather than thinking through a reasoned response.

Comment: @Michael - good edit!  Note that what the router says about the name and type is based on [OUI lookup](https://www.wireshark.org/tools/oui-lookup.html) so anyone changing their MAC can "be" whatever they want.  I agree that jumping to DDoSing is a bad choice.

Answer (score 0):

Simply change your encryption to WPA2 and Change your password to a combination of alphanumeric word with special characters, use a combination of words from atleast 2 languages peppered with special characters and numbers. Change password regularly. And uncheck WPS on router config page.

Answer (score 0):

Pressing CLEAR just clears the list of addresses the RG has seen.  As soon as it "sees" them again, they'll return to the list.

You can set up MAC filters to prevent addresses from connecting, but that would be high maintenance (unblock when they come over, block when they leave).  Devices that report names (e.g. Windows PC's) show up with names in the list.  Some versions of the RG firmware have allowed you to assign names to some devices, but they usually didn't survive an RG reboot, making this exercise rather fruitless.

What you might want to do is get a third party wireless router that has time of day filtering and specific guest access and hook that up behind your RG as described in post 2 in this thread.

For more info, you can read more on my site: [How to Kick People off your WiFi Network](https://www.techykeeday.com/how-to-kick-people-off-your-wifi/)

Comment: if you are going to link to your own site, please disclose your relationship to the link so people understand the potential bias

Answer (score -1):

1. Changed your WiFi password, and ideally also the SSID.
2. Reboot your router.

Problem solved.

Don't bother trying to D.O.S the device. You'll ultimately just increase your exposure. If this is a moderately experienced hacker, they will be more than capable of handling any counter-attack you might launch.

Answer (score -1):

Allow only the known MAC addresses in the router DHCP server, so DHCP will issue IP addresses only to the known hosts.